# convert angularJS function to a react function

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, reactjs

I'm currently trying to use an angular feature, but I cant use ng-click inside an a react app.

I am trying to convert the following function to a react function, I'm aware of `axios`, not sure how to approach blade variables in react.

I need the angular snippet to do be converted into a react function.

**Angular(main.js)**

```
$scope.myfollow = function(user) {
    $http.post('/user/follow/'+ user.id).then(function(result) {
        console.log("user id is:"+ user.id);
    });
};
```

**React file**

```
render(){
    return(

       <div className="followdoe">      
            <button  onClick={ this.btnClick.bind(this) } className={this.state.className}>
                   <p>{ this.state.btnText }</p>
            </button>
       </div>


    )
}
```

**Route.php**

```
Route::post('user/follow/{id}', 'UserController@my_follow');
```

**Profile.blade.php**

```
<div style="margin:30px 0px;">

    <button class="follow-button" ng-click="myfollow({{$user}});">+ Follow</button>
</div>
```

**UserController.php**

```
    public function my_follow(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();

        if($user->id != $id && $otherUser = User::find($id)){

            $user->toggleFollow($otherUser);
        }

    }
   public function getProfile($user)
    {  
        $user = User::with(['posts.likes' => function($query) {
                            $query->whereNull('deleted_at');
                        }, 'follow','follow.follower'])
                      ->where('name','=', $user)->first();



        if(!$user){
            return redirect('404');
        }

        return view ('profile')->with('user', $user);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the `user` data in your React component?

Comment: i don't tholle, how would i do that

Comment: Your question is about how you should port your angular `myfollow` function to React. I'm not sure how your data looks beyond that, I'm afraid.

Comment: What data ? i just want a way to make the same angular function but in react, would you have an idea on how to do that ? thanks tholle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function on your component and use the [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API.

**Example**

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      className: "test",
      btnText: "Text",
      user: { id: 123 }
    };
    this.myfollow = this.myfollow.bind(this);
    this.btnClick = this.btnClick.bind(this);
  }

  myfollow(user) {
    fetch(`/user/follow/${user.id}`, { method: "POST" })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  };

  btnClick() {
    this.myfollow(this.state.user);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="followdoe">
        <button onClick={this.btnClick} className={this.state.className}>
          <p>{this.state.btnText}</p>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the my follow function is giving a syntax error, im trying to figure it out

Comment: unexpected token somewhere near `myfollow = user`

Comment: @BARNOWL Alright. I updated the answer. You might not have [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) in your development environment, which my previous version of the answer used.

Comment: perfect, it build successful let me give this a shot.

Comment: @BARNOWL Yes, that's what my second question above was about. Do you have the `user` data in your React component? Since you use `user.id` in your angular code, you need the `user.id` for the URL.

Comment: that is correct, i need the user.id for the url. I don't have user data in my react component, just the `user:{ id: ''}`

Comment: so maybe i need to set the state to a blade $user parameter

Comment: @BARNOWL Yes, that might work. You need to get the `$user` data into your component state somehow to make it work.

Comment: like `user:{ id: {$user} }`  is that how i would do it ?

Comment: @BARNOWL I'm not sure how to get Blade data into a JavaScript file, sadly. You are much better at that than me, that much I know.